# use proxy model to change cell's background color of a QTableView after values are changed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a subclassed `QAbstractTableModel`

which contains None Type Values to display the rows as empty

```
class ViewModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, input_data=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.input_data = input_data or [[None, None],[None, None]]
```

I want to change the colors of the cells if the inserted values (replacing the None Type Values) are in /out a certain range

like `z = 12 <= x <= 20`

`#  False == red, True == green`

the color should only change if the items are edited or
`self.model.layoutChanged.emit()` gets executed

the answers to change cell's background color of a QTableView are suggesting to make changes in the data method [How to change cell's background color of a QTableView [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56567353/11702787)

but this is going to color the cells right at the beginning

I have found an approach in the QT forum to insert a proxy model between the view and the model
[How to simply change the background color of a cell inside a TableView](https://forum.qt.io/topic/85973/how-to-simply-change-the-background-colour-of-a-cell-inside-a-tableview)

I'm trying to implement the code into Pyqt5, unsuccessful so far. Is there a PyQt5 approach which I'm unaware of?

example code

```
import sys
import re

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc


class ViewModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, input_data=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.input_data = input_data or [[None, None],[None, None]]



    def data(self, index, role):  # parameter index, role are needed !
        if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                text = self.input_data[index.row()][index.column()]
            except IndexError:
                text = None

            return text

    def rowCount(self, index=qtc.QModelIndex()):
        return 0 if index.isValid() else len(self.input_data)


    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self.input_data[0])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is which index of the orientation
        if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == qtc.Qt.Vertical:
                return "row"

    def flags(self, index):
        return qtc.Qt.ItemIsEditable | qtc.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | qtc.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def setData(self, index, value, role=qtc.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == qtc.Qt.EditRole:
            try:
                row = index.row()
                column = index.column()

                pattern = '^[\d]+(?:,[\d]+)?$'


                if re.fullmatch(pattern, value, flags=0):
                    print("true")
                    self.input_data[row][column] = value  # float
                else:
                    print("nope")
                    pass

                return True

            except ValueError:
                print("not a number")
                return False


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):



    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # View
        table_view = qtw.QTableView()

        self.model = ViewModel()

        table_view.setModel(self.model)

        # size and position
        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = qtw.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
        # size
        self.resize(1000, 410)

        # layout
        qvboxlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        qvboxlayout.addWidget(table_view)

        self.setLayout(qvboxlayout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a proxy to change the color then only the `data()` method should be overridden:

```
class ColorProxy(qtc.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def data(self, index, role=qtc.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == qtc.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            data = index.data()
            try:
                value = float(data)
            except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
                print("error:", e)
            else:
                return qtg.QColor("green") if 12 <= value <= 20 else qtg.QColor("red")
        return super().data(index, role)
```

```
# ...
self.model = ViewModel()

proxy = ColorProxy()
proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

table_view.setModel(proxy)
# ...
```

Another solution is to use a delegate

```
class ColorDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        data = index.data()
        try:
            value = float(data)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
            print("error:", e)
        else:
            color = qtg.QColor("green") if 12 <= value <= 20 else qtg.QColor("red")
            option.backgroundBrush = color
```

```
# ...
table_view = qtw.QTableView()

self.model = ViewModel()

delegate = ColorDelegate(table_view)
table_view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

table_view.setModel(self.model)
# ...
```

Comment: what is the purpose of super in `return super().data(index, role)` ?